# Embed credentials for external data source into Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm pulling data from a web source (REST API) into Excel. I go to Data > Get Data > From Other Sources > From Web.

I then enter the endpoint URL, and on the next screen enter credentials with Basic authentication. All works fine, except that when I send this spreadsheet to the next person, the Basic auth credentials are not included.

**How do I preserve these in the file/ connection?** No other form of authentication (Windows, for example) is an option.

I've tried exporting the connection itself, but only the URL is persisted; the credentials are not included with the connection .odc file.

Comment: I hope I'm wrong, but I'm sure credentials save to the computer/laptop. I often create reports this way but out of SQL server and have always had to go and physically enter the credentials on any new persons laptop, (or you can do it over screen share, TeamViewer etc.)